# Python Twisted- run() method not recognised

Tags: python, twisted, reactor, twisted.internet

Given below is the code for a server:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataRecvd(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000,EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I get the following error:

```
listenTCP()- Undefined variable from import

run- Undefined variable from import
```

I am using pydev with eclipse on windows 7. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `s/dataRecvd/dataReceived/`. Just copy-paste the server example from [Twisted home page](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It works as is.

Answer (score 1):

[image]try rhis  add #@UndefinedVariable like:

```
reactor.listenTCP(8000,EchoFactory())  #@UndefinedVariable
reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

Comment: No, still no output. What are they supposed to do anyway? And the error went away but the execution does not give any output

Comment: @Prakhar Mohan Srivastava:can you try the same code on python shell

Comment: @Prakhar Mohan Srivastava Just try to explore twisted.internet you will not find  the reactor object When Eclipse/PyDev tries to compile the bytecodedoesn't see the reactor object in the twisted but it will present at runtime

Comment: I tried it on the shell too, the program starts executing then nothing. There is no output.

Answer (score 1):

> listenTCP()- Undefined variable from import

This isn't a Python exception.  I guess it's an "error" from a tool like pylint.  It's spurious.  It means nothing.

> I tried it on the shell too, the program starts executing then nothing. There is no output.

Do you know what the program is supposed to do?  It isn't supposed to produce any output in the shell.

Comment: According to the book that I am referring, its supposed to do something like:

`Server said: Hello`

Comment: The book is wrong or you are mis-interpreting it.  There's no chance this block of code will behave that way.

Comment: Okay. :/ Weird, I am referring the wrong book. I'll just refer the documentation then.